# docker login Remote error from secret service

Tags: docker, docker-registry, container-registry

While logging in with:

```
$ docker login registry.mydomain.com
```

I received this error:

> Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
>
> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login`

Comment: I have the same error, no idea how to solve it yet, I saw suggestions to installing gnome-keyring, but it didn't resolve it